# Fragment ListView ContextMenu with Dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, contextmenu, fragmentmanager

I have a `ListView` that is within a `Fragment`. The `ListView` has a `ContextMenu` to edit and delete entries. I am attempting to launch a custom `Dialog` with the selection of `EDIT` from the `ContextMenu` but it will not accept my code. I have been using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` in like fashion with success up until this point. The given response is `Cannot resolve method 'show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)` Any advice or input to what can be changed is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Fragment:

```
    public static class FragmentS extends Fragment {

    private ListView saveListView;
    private List<LiftSave> LiftSaves = new ArrayList<LiftSave>();
    private static final int EDIT = 0, DELETE = 1;

    LiftSave longClickedItemLiftSave;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> saveAdapter;


    public FragmentS() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_s,
                container, false);
        saveListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saveListView);
        registerForContextMenu(saveListView);
        DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler (getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        if (dbHandler.getLiftSavesCount() != 0)
            LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves());

        populateList();

        saveListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                longClickedItemLiftSave = (LiftSave) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void populateList() {
        saveAdapter = new SaveListAdapter();
        saveListView.setAdapter(saveAdapter);
    }


    public class SaveListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> {
            public SaveListAdapter() {
                super(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, LiftSaves);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null)
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

                LiftSave currentLiftSave = LiftSaves.get(position);

                TextView liftName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftName);
                liftName.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftName());
                TextView maxValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.maxValue);
                maxValue.setText(currentLiftSave.getMaxValue());
                TextView weightAndReps = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weightAndReps);
                weightAndReps.setText(currentLiftSave.getRepsAndWeight());
                TextView liftNotes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftNotes);
                liftNotes.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftNotes());
                TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.todayDate);
                date.setText(currentLiftSave.getTodayDate());

                return view;
            }

    }
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.pencil_icon);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Save Options");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT, menu.NONE, "Edit Save");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE, menu.NONE, "Delete Save");
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case EDIT:
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();

                //problem line
                myDialog.show(manager, "MyDialog");
                //problem line

                break;

            case DELETE:

                dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                dbHandler.deleteLiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                saveAdapter.remove(longClickedItemLiftSave);


                break;
        }
               return super.
               onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Confirm that your dialog fragment is extended from android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0):

you have two possibilities to do what you want:

so if your MyDialog() is Fragment you can't use .show() - instead you should change your fragment like that:

```
    manager.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.container, myDialog).commit();
```

or if your MyDialog() is a DialogFragment you shoud show it like that:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    MyDialog() myDialog = new MyDialog();

    myDialog.show( ft, "" );
```

Comment: Aleizdein, thanks for your reply. It is indeed a `DialogFragment`, the `fragment` from which I am calling this one is setup in the manner you mentioned first. I might be missing something but I would have to call `FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` for the second manner you mentioned (the right track I believe) to work. Leaving `MyDialog()` of the next line expecting a method call, and `myDialog` as a symbol unable to be resolved.